# Java reader.readLine() dosn't return the exact line in the file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, readline

hey guys i have been using  BufferedReader and actually i havn't notice this exact problem until I didn't find some words, I am trying to replace some words in my file and I encountered that by this method I am not getting the exact result I am expecting which is the same line in the file this is my code down there

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(
                          new FileInputStream("C:\\files\\myfile.rtf"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\files\\my2file.rtf")));
    String str;

    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);

    str = str.replace("CivClient", "myname"); // doesn't work
    str = str.replace("AdresseClient", "myname"); // doesn't work
    str = str.replace("lastname", "myname");
    str = str.replace("firstname", "myname");

    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
```

executing this code I found out that, the word "CivClient" isn't appearing as it is but separated
this is part of the log, not all of it. you will notice that the word isn't appearing as it is.
thank you for your effort. dear stackoverflowers.

> VOS PRESTATIONS\~:\line <}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \insrsid5071958 C}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0  \insrsid10116111
>   iv}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5071958 `C`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 `lient`> <}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \insrsid13635392\charrsid13635392 `lastname`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 > <}{ \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \insrsid13635392\charrsid13635392 `firstname`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0
>   \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 >\line <}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0
>   \insrsid5071958 `A`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111
>   `dresse`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0  \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5071958
>   `C`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 lient>\line
>   <}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid13635392
>   `CPClient`}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 >
>   <}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid13635392 
>   VilleClient}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid10116111 >

Comment: Please properly format your example. Also, please try not to write to the same file you're reading from, especially when using a different encoding. That could mess with the results. Instead write to a temp file and when successful delete the old one and copy/move the temp file to replace it (or alternatively copy the temp file's contents into the original file).

Comment: As a way to determine if your problem is in the reader or in your replace statements, does the file get printed out exactly like the original when you comment out the str.replace lines?

Comment: Could you clearify how the data is structured that you read, what exactly is the output you get and what you're expecting?

Comment: Read and writing the same file at once is a bad idea, don't do it unless you want to dive into filesystem specifics.

Comment: yeah the document is printed so clearly with other placeholders, the problem here is that some words on the readline() dosn't apear as others and some are replaced and the others are not ,
@BreakBB it's just an rtf file i am reading the placeholder is <CivClient> but the problem is all of the other words are being replaced only this one. 
 i am not reading and writing at the same time i changed the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Evidently the file contains RTF, rich text, instead of plain text - as the .rtf file ending suggested already. Also `\rtlch` probably means right-to-left-characters. You might use swing's `StyledDocument`, the RTFEditorKit, to read the file.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\files\\myfile.rtf");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String rtf = new String(content, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
StringReader in = new StringReader(rtf);
RTFEditorKit kit = new RTFEditorKit();
Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
kit.read(in, doc, 0);
String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
```

The code is a bit step-by-step, one can immediately read - as you did.

---

***Writing the text back to the file:***

The problem is the RTF nature. As you have seen that "CivClient" is split in the middle with different RTF attributes, the simplest solution is to create a *correct* RTF manually. Remove the garbage in the word.

Then your code would work:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\files\\myfile.rtf");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String str = new String(content, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
str = str.replace("CivClient", "myname");
str = str.replace("AdresseClient", "myname");
str = str.replace("lastname", "myname");
str = str.replace("firstname", "myname");
content = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
Files.write(path, content);
```

ISO-8859-1, Latin-1, is a limited character set. Taking advantage of UTF-16 support in RTF:

```
str = str.chars()
    .map(ch -> ch < 128 ? Character.toString(ch) : String.format("\\u%04X", (int)ch))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Which converts special chars into the format `\uXXXX`.

Comment: thank you sir for your responsive answear, but can you please clarify how i can edit the existing file by this method ? i am still a beginner at this.

Comment: The string `text` will contain the file's content. If you want to _edit / change_ the file, it means changing the document and writing it back. I'll try to add code.

Answer (score 0):

It's either like that in your source file, or your attempt to 'in-place rewrite' by streaming the input as you're writing to the same file, is causing this issue. Generally, write to a new file, and when you're done, move the new file over the old file (after closing all streams). Alternatively, use RandomAccessFile and overwrite in-place, but note that to overwrite in place you can't remove or add characters (only replace them). That's a limitation of file systems, not java.

NB: You're reading with an enforced charset: ISO_8859_1. But when writing you don't do this. That means on any system where the platform default charset encoding is not ISO_8859_1, this job won't just replace CivClient and 'less than' symbols, it also recodes the entire charset, you might want to fix that too.

Comment: actually i am using 2 diffrent files 1 for the writing and one for reading,
about the forcing the charset , i just wanted to try that maybe the readline() function changes the output. i have tried with none , and diffrent others charset but i got nothing. its always the same problem